# DynamoDB scan : Does not return correct values

Tags: swift, swift3, amazon-dynamodb

I have written the following function but I have a problem with its returning value.

In my console I can see the results pulled from AWS dynamoDB, I can even display it. As you can see, I am printing item variable.

I instantiated an array in my function and append each item pulled from AWS to it but it returning nil.

Can you please see what I miss in my code thanks.

```
func scanClientList(_ startFromBeginning: Bool) -> [Client]{

        var clients = [Client]()
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()
        let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBScanExpression()
        //queryExpression.exclusiveStartKey = self.userId
        queryExpression.limit = 20
        dynamoDBObjectMapper.scan(Client.self, expression: queryExpression).continueWith(executor: AWSExecutor.mainThread(), block: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if let paginatedOutput = task.result {
                for item in paginatedOutput.items as! [Client] {
                    print("ITEMS: \(item)")
                    clients.append(item)
                }

                if paginatedOutput.lastEvaluatedKey == nil {

                }
            }
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false

            if let error = task.error as? NSError {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
            return nil
        })
        return clients
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually my function here works perfectly, I didn't initialize the variable clients in the functions

I had something like

```
var clients = [Client]()?
```

and changed it to

```
var clients:Array<Client> = []
```